# Sending multiple data with SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

Here is index.html codes;

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="send.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="ad_soyad" size="25"><br />
Telephone: <input type="text" name="tel" size="25"><br />
E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email"  size="25"><br />
Address: <textarea rows="5" name="adres"  cols="25"></textarea><br />
Message: <textarea rows="5" name="mesaj"  cols="25"></textarea><br /> 
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Gonder"> 
</form>
```

Here is send.php codes:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                    
$mail->Host = 'blablabla.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     
$mail->Username = 'blablabla.com';                
$mail->Password = 'password';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
$mail->Port = 587;

if(($ad_soyad=="") or ($tel =="") or ($email=="") or ($mesaj=="")){

echo "<center>Please fill the required fields.<br><a href=index.html>Go back</a></center>";

}
else
{

$mail->setFrom($_POST['email']);
$mail->addAddress('contact@blablabla.com', 'BlaBlaBla');        

$mail->isHTML(true);                              
$mail->Subject='Contact Form Message';
$mail->Body = ($_POST['mesaj']);


$smtp = new SMTP;    
//Enable connection-level debug output
$smtp->do_debug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent.';
}


}

?>
```

It works.
But only sends name,email and message.
So, I want to add more field like telephone or address or etc.
but i can not put them into $mail->body when i tried to write telephone and message together
it gives me error:"not configured properly "
I have to use SMTP because my hosting only provides SMTP..
how can i send all datas which form gets from user ,with SMTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve the issue - I can't understand why it should fail if you add more content to the message body but as you have not shown that I can only guess it was done in such a way as to make invalid markup?

```
<?php

    /* Are these variables defined before this point? */
    if( ( $ad_soyad=="" ) or ( $tel =="" ) or ( $email=="" ) or ( $mesaj=="" ) ){
        echo "<center>Please fill the required fields.<br><a href=index.html>Go back</a></center>";
    } else {

        /* only load the libraries if the above variables are not empty */
        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();                                    
        $mail->Host = 'blablabla.com'; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     
        $mail->Username = 'blablabla.com';                
        $mail->Password = 'password';                          
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
        $mail->Port = 587;


        /* some basic filtering of user supplied variables */
        $email=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
        $message=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'mesaj', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $name=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'ad_soyad', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $tel=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'tel', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $address=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'adres', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );


        /* prepare message components */
        $msg=array();
        $msg[]="Name:".$name;
        $msg[]="Phone:".$tel;
        $msg[]="Address:".$address;
        $msg[]="Message:".$message;




        $mail->setFrom( $email );
        $mail->addAddress('contact@blablabla.com', 'BlaBlaBla');        
        $mail->isHTML(true);                              
        $mail->Subject='Contact Form Message';
        $mail->Body = implode( "\r\n", $msg );


        $smtp = new SMTP;    
        //Enable connection-level debug output
        $smtp->do_debug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;

        if( !$mail->send() ) {
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message sent.';
        }
        $mail = $smtp = null;
    }
?>
```